# How do I createa a new object of the correct type in a Swift generic function?

Tags: generics, swift3

I have the following Swift generic method:

```
  static func getRecords<T>(_ which: Which, from table: Table, completionHandler: @escaping ([T]) -> Void)
  {
    let url: String = DatabaseInterface.getUrl(which, from: table)
    Http.get(url: url)
    {
      response, error in
      if nil != error
      {
        print("get\(table.rawValue)() failed; error = \(error!)")
        return
      }

      var objects: [T] = []
      let formatter = DateFormatter()
      formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd" // Matches PHP's "Y-m-d" \Date format.

      let records = (response!["records"])!
      for record in (records as! [NSDictionary])
      {
        // This line fails with the error
        // 'T' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers
        objects.append(T(fromDictionary: record as! [String: Any]))
      }
      DispatchQueue.main.async
      {
        completionHandler(objects)
      }
    }
  }
```

The Http.get() method retrieves records from a server and decodes the JSON into an array of dictionaries.

The objects.append() line fails with this error:

> 'T' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers

My first question: Is it possible to create a new instance of a type specified by a type placeholder in a generic function?

My second question: If it is possible, what is the correct syntax to do so?

Comment: The compiler has no clue that `T` has an initializer. You need to constrain it to a protocol or class that contains `init(fromDictionary:)`

Comment: Hmmm. Guess it's time to study up on type constraints. Thanks!

Comment: As a side note, you shouldn't use `NSDictionary` in Swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler has no clue that T has an initializer. You need to constrain it to a protocol or class that contains init(fromDictionary:)

```
protocol JSONInitializable {
    init(fromDictionary: [String: Any])
}

static func getRecords<T: JSONInitializable>(
    _ which: Which,
    from table: Table,
    completionHandler: @escaping ([T]) -> Void
    ) {
    let url = DatabaseInterface.getUrl(which, from: table)
    Http.get(url: url) { _response, error in
    guard let response = _response as? [String: [[String: Any]]],
        error == nil else {
        print("get\(table.rawValue)() failed; error = \(error!)")
        return
    }

    guard let objects = response["records"]?.map(T.init(fromDictionary:)) {
        fatalError("`response` doesn't have a value for the key \"records\".")
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async { completionHandler(objects) }
}
```

Comment: Nice solution. I'll have to update what I came up with. I really need to remember that most (all?) collections in Swift have map().

Comment: @DavidPatterson Not just all collections, but all sequences, too.